# Give multiple permissions to a role - Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

How can we assign multiple permissions to a single role at once?

```
    $permission1 = Permission::create(['name' => 'Create Client']);
    $permission2 = Permission::create(['name' => 'View Invoice']);
    $permission3 = Permission::create(['name' => 'Add Product']);

    $role = Role::findById(1);

    $role->givePermissionTo($permission1);
```

In above, I'm only giving permission to the first one.

As this is also achived by,   `$role->syncPermissions($permissions);`  Im confused how $permission includes multiple permissions?

Any advice please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you can pass an array to [`givePermissionTo`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Traits/HasPermissions.php#L263), so you could just do the following:

```
$permission1 = Permission::create(['name' => 'Create Client']);
$permission2 = Permission::create(['name' => 'View Invoice']);
$permission3 = Permission::create(['name' => 'Add Product']);

$role = Role::findById(1);
$role->givePermissionTo([$permission1, $permission2, $permission3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can pass multiple permissions in array to `givePermissionTo()`.
2. If you want to detach previously assigned permissions to the role, use `syncPermissions()`
3. Or you can even use laravel's sync method as Role has `morphToMany` relation with Permissions. so `$role->permissions()->sync($permissions);` also work

Answer (score 2):

hello my suggestion is to use

$role = Role::findById(1);
$role->givePermissionTo(Permission::all());